# Guardar datos de un formulario html en un PDF

Tags: php, html, formularios, pdf

Tengo un formulario en index.html y cuando el usuario presiona el botón "Enviar", lo redirecciona a solicitud.php y simplemente aparece un mensaje diciendo que sus datos fueron capturados. Mi pregunta es, cómo puedo guardar esos datos para ingresarlos en un PDF y que en el momento de que se le dió click a "Enviar" el pdf se descargue en automático. Además, los pdfs que se generen tengo que guardarlos en otro archivo llamado "registros.php".

En index.html tengo esto:

```
<form class = "formulario" id = "formulario" role="form" action="enviodemail.php" method="POST" >

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="titulo">Título de la obra *</label>
              <input id="titulo" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú ]+" name="titulo" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fecha">Fecha de creación *</label>
              <input id="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
```

Y lo que intenté fue lo siguiente, dentro de solicitud puse esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sub-navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="input-1">Cultura</a>
</div>
</div>
</nav><main id="main-container">
<div class="container top-buffer-submenu bottom-buffer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

            <h2 align="left">Formato"</h2>
            <br></br>

              Datos capturados correctamente.

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</main></body>
</html>
<?php
require ("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf -> AddPage();
$pdf -> SetFont("Arial", "B", 16);
$pdf -> Cell(10, 10, "Welcome", 0, 0, C);
$pdf -> output("prueba.pdf");
?>
</html>
```

En registros.php tengo esto:

```
<?php 
$titulo =   isset( $_POST['titulo'] ) ? $_POST['titulo'] : '';
$fecha =   isset( $_POST['fecha'] ) ? $_POST['fecha'] : '';
?>
```

Comment: puedes hacer uso de javascript o una libreria aqui un [articulo](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-convert-html-with-css-to-pdf-using-javascript) , intentalo y nos dices como te resulto

Comment: Sí pude solucionarlo, con FPDF. c:

Comment: ok, puedes agregar tu propia respuesta tal vez le sea util a alguien mas.